# How can I click on a specific link?

Tags: selenium, browser, hyperlink

I'm making an app (console application) similar to a search engine. The app asks the user for input, then it googles that input and gathers the URLs of the first page of Google results. Then, it asks the user which link does he want to open, for example: "Which link should I open?" and the user should type "First", "Second", "Third", etc. I have managed to get to the point where I gather all URLs, but I don't know how to code the part where I *choose* which URL I want it to open.

Here's the code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Search for:");  //User Input
string command = Console.ReadLine();
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com"); //Opens Firefox, Goes to Google.
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

IWebElement searchInput = driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib"));
searchInput.SendKeys(command); //Types User Input in "Search"
searchInput.SendKeys(Keys.Enter); //Hits "Enter"

//Gets Urls
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
By linkLocator = By.CssSelector("cite._Rm");
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(linkLocator));
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(linkLocator);
foreach (IWebElement link in links)
{
    Console.WriteLine(link.Text);
}
```

Comment: User will run application with search phrase and then choose link he wants to open? In console? With opened browser? Why user can't just handle all operations in browser? What is the point of using console?

Comment: Well, actually, it's an early version of a "Jarvis" app i'm making. I want the user to say "Google Einstein" (for exampe) and when the app gets to the result page, i want the user to say "First result" or "Second Result" and the app automatically clicks on. I'm just truing to get the hand of the code right  now! :)

Comment: Have you considered making a browser plug-in to do this? You'd have all the browser functionality already built it... you could just add the voice activation portion. Just a thought...

Comment: Sounds good, but i have no idea where to start. Could you provide some links? :)

Comment: Selenium is a test tool, and though what you've described is possible, it is not designed for this purpose. I recommend you look through these: https://www.google.co.nz/?gws_rd=ssl#q=how+to+write+firefox+plugin